# Injecting an API call between two queries to MySQL that are dependent on a sequential response

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

On my backend Node.js Express API, I need to connect to a MySQL database, run a query to get some information. Then using that information, make a call to an external API. Then finally, after getting that response, I need to use the external information in a second query to my database.

I have a function that currently works to accomplish the tasks described, but in my Chrome dev tools, the request is never marked as resolved. This is causing my promise on the front end never to move on to the next function in its chain.

```
app.get('/api/update/:id', (req, res) => {
    const ID = req.params.id;
    connectionPool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) {throw err;}
        const queryA = `SELECT infoA FROM table WHERE id = "${ID}"`;
        connection.query(queryA, (error, results, fields) => {
            const infoA = results[0].infoA;
            externalAPICall(infoA).then(res => {
                let infoB = res;
                const queryB = `UPDATE table SET infoB = "${infoB}" WHERE id = "${ID}"`;
                connection.query(query);
                connection.release();
            });
        });
    })
})
```

Then on the front end, sending a request to this API route

```
updateInfo = (id) => {
    axios.get(`${API_ROOT}/api/update/${id}`)
    .then(res => {
        this.getAllInfo();
    });
}
```

I expect to have the front end trigger the request to the `api/update/id` route, and infoA to be selected from the db, used in the external API call for info B, then update infoB into the db. After the front end receives confirmation this is done, it will run a function to query the full table with updated information in the `getAllInfo` function.

Right now, my table successfully updates itself from the external API, however the front end receives no response from the API, so it never seems to move on to the `getAllInfo` function call. I've tried putting `res.status(200).send(results)` in my API route, but either winds up breaking the chain if it's too early, or if it's right at the end, it gives an error saying `res` is not defined.

I feel like I'm missing something very small that will make it all work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't sending any  response from the request handler.  You need a `res.send(...)` or a `res.json(...)` when your request handler code is done with its work.

And, you need to change the argument in this:

```
externalAPICall(infoA).then(res => { ...});
```

to some parameter name other than `res` because that is hiding the higher scoped `res` that you need to use with `res.send()` or `res.json()`.

You can do something like this:

```
app.get('/api/update/:id', (req, res) => {
    const ID = req.params.id;
    connectionPool.getConnection((error, connection) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }
        const queryA = `SELECT infoA FROM table WHERE id = "${ID}"`;
        connection.query(queryA, (error, results, fields) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(err);
                res.sendStatus(500);
                return;
            }
            const infoA = results[0].infoA;
            externalAPICall(infoA).then(infoB => {
                const queryB = `UPDATE table SET infoB = "${infoB}" WHERE id = "${ID}"`;
                connection.query(query, (error, results, fields) => {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(err);
                        res.sendStatus(500);
                    } else {
                        res.send("success");
                    }
                    connection.release();
                });

            });
        });
    })
})
```

Note: This could be a lot cleaner to code, to handle errors centrally and to maintain if you were using a promise interface in the mysql2 interface.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something small, but it would have taken me forever to figure out I was overwriting the res keyword. Definitely a valuable lesson. I'll look into the mysql2 promise interface next to try and clean this thing up. Thanks again.

Comment: @DaleSpiteri - Note all the places I added error handling too.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you sanitize your url param, because your code looks vulnerable to sql injections to me.

Better use placeholder variables in your query. Example copied [from](https://blog.hailstone.io/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-nodejs/).

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM bank_accounts WHERE dob = ? AND bank_account = ?",
    [
     req.body.dob,
     req.body.account_number
    ],
    function(error, results) { 

    }
);
```

Or if you want to use named placeholder:

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM bank_accounts WHERE dob = :dob AND bank_account = :account_number",
    {
     dob: req.body.dob,
     account_number: req.body.account_number
    },
    function(error, results) { 

    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I have been using placeholders in my app, but I thought it might be easier to read my issue with them written out as full SQL strings. I didn't know that placeholders sanitized the query though. Good heads up.